# How to change emission of a material via script?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

How can i change emission of a material via script? I cant find any documentation for that on Unity page.

Comment: Googling "unity change properties of material" quickly led to the appropriate documentation: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/MaterialsAccessingViaScript.html

Comment: @Serlite In N1ckGreek's defence, Unity's documentation is patchy at best - in this case, what he wants to do can only be found in the source of the standard shader (or after a lot of searching around on forums etc).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you're using the standard shader, and depending on if your emission is a colour or a texture, then:

Texture:

```
material.SetTexture("_EmissionMap",yourNewEmissionTexture);
```

Colour:

```
material.SetColor("_EmissionColor",yourNewEmissionColour);
```

The easiest way to get this information is to take a look at the source of the built in shaders which can be found [in the Unity download archive](https://unity3d.com/get-unity/download/archive) under the "Built in shaders" option.

Comment: It's a Color, I tried the second code before but i was getting an error. I will try it again later.

Comment: @N1ckGreek You've tried with `_EmissionColor`? The answer got edited after I double checked :)